# OpenCV Android camera app pause no work

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I just started an other camera app base on OpenCV while running an OpenCV camera app yet on Android,and then have a problem.

First,I started an OpenCV camera app (App-One) on my Android device,and it working fine, everything was OK.

Then, I started an other OpenCV camera app (App-Two) on my Android device,and it working fine too, the App-One was Pause,but no quit.

Finally, I quit the App-Two,and the system return me to App-One.

Everything sounds OK,but when I return to App-One, I found it(App-One) was not work,and there is a dialog says "It seems that you device does not support camera (or it is locked). Application will be closed."

I had started the App-One,and it was OK.

But I just open an other ,and return to App-One,it tell me is not OK. How do I solve this?

T_T Help me.

Answer (score 0):

> Caution: Remember to release the Camera object by calling the Camera.release() when your application is done using it! If your application does not properly release the camera, all subsequent attempts to access the camera, including those by your own application, will fail and may cause your or other applications to be shut down.
>
> Caution: Always check for exceptions when using Camera.open(). Failing to check for exceptions if the camera is in use or does not exist will cause your application to be shut down by the system.

[From documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

I think you should release the camera when application is paused, because you can open only one camera at a time.